# How can i keep an activity alive, if it's the solution

Tags: java, android, android-intent

So i got two activities, a main then a secondary, we'll call them activity_A (main) and activity B( the second ).
So my activity_A is getting some data, then sending it to activity_B with this code :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,activity_B.class);
        i.putExtra("Charge_Batterie", bat);
        startActivity(i);
```

activity_B receive it correctly with this code :

```
String bat = getIntent().getStringExtra("Charge_Batterie");
```

My problem is that my activity_A is refreashing it's value "bat", so when i send it with intent it doesn't refreash in activity_B.
So i'm wondering, is my activity_A sleeping ? If yes how can i make it stay alive ?

Comment: Intents have persisted data. Once set it will remain like that until explicitly set again.

Comment: If you want to scan Battery it s better to use a Service. but if it s just a value from activity A to B. there should be another problem with assigning value to variables.

Comment: In my activity_B i'll be using a onRefresh() method from android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout. So if i call my getIntent in the onRefresh, it will override it right ?

Comment: No, an Intent is a one time container.

Comment: So the only way is the "Service". I'll check how it works and try to do it. Thank's Everyone for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m doing the same thing and it works for a long time - activity A runs a timer and launches activity B with extras.
When I want to refresh activity B with "new extras", I´m doing this:

```
                // check if activity B is created and running:
                if (intent == null) {
                    System.out.println("Creating Activity  - Intent is null");
                    intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
                    intent.putExtras(ImagedownloaderActivityBundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Reloading Activity  - Intent exists");
                    finish();
                    intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
                    intent.removeExtra("playlistsList");
                    intent.putExtras(ImagedownloaderActivityBundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

As far as I know, this isn´t the best way to achieve the background task - it should be running on a service, perhaps doing the same when one needs to refresh.

Comment: This looks cool but in my case both activity_A and activity_B are displaying a view, so with this code my application is stuck on the activity_B

Comment: Solution to this should be running a service - it can be kept running and update or relaunch your activity when some condition is met.